# How can we turn hash sha256 of a passphase into an EC_key private key?

Tags: c, hash, openssl, cryptography

i have a question, i just practice C & OpenSSL recently & notice this is the common way to create EC_Key:

```
    EC_KEY *eckey = EC_KEY_new();
    EC_GROUP *ecgroup= EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp192k1);
    int set_group_status = EC_KEY_set_group(eckey,ecgroup);
    int gen_status = EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);
```

This method generate EC_key based on a random interger. May i ask if is there any code that we can declare a hash sha256 of a passphase & make it private key of a EC_key we just create since i read that EC_key's private key has the same format with hash sha256?

```
//Example
char* exam = "somewhere over the rainbow";
unsigned char output[32];
SHA256(exam, strlen(exam), output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly for that curve.

An ECC private key is actually a random integer less than the order of the base point, or equivalently the order of the group generated by the base point.

Although it is not true for all ECC curves (groups), the X9/Certicom/NIST *prime* curves were generated so that the generated group order is equal to the *curve* order (formally, cofactor = 1), and the curve order is always close to the underlying field order which for these curves was chosen very close to 2<sup>N</sup>. 
Thus a private key for a *256-bit* prime curve, like P-256/secp256r1 (commonly used in TLS, and SSH, and some other applications) or secp256k1 (used in Bitcoin and some derivative coins), is *almost* a random 256-bit string -- close enough that in practice it will work.

Similarly for secp192k1 a random *192-bit* string is close enough, and could be generated by taking the **first 192 bits of** a SHA-256 output (or last, or middle, if you prefer) as long as it was computed on input (your passphrase) having sufficient entropy to provide the desired security.

If by passphrase you mean a phrase chosen by a person, no. There is abundant evidence that people do *not* choose randomly even when they try to, and passwords and passphrases chosen by people, and not 'strengthened' cryptographically which your method does not, are regularly broken. As an example, [this was tried in the Bitcoin community a few years ago under the name 'brain wallet'](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Brainwallet#Obsolete_Brainwallet_Style) -- i.e. your private key, giving access to your bitcoins, is in your brain. Many of these keys were broken and the bitcoins stolen.

If you mean a series of words (not really a meaningful phrase) generated *randomly* by the computer to have sufficient entropy, or by some other process that actually is random like rolling fair dice, then yes. The current standard in Bitcoin for a 'seed phrase' is 12 words from a list of 2048 giving 128 bits of entropy plus 4 bits of redundancy; for your curve you only need 96 bits of entropy so 9 such words would work (although it isn't standard). Numerous other similar schemes have been developed and used over the years. In practice you will probably have to write this 'phrase' down and/or store it somewhere, and then secure that storage appropriately.

Comment: no need to worry about security, i just try to program. So are there any specific method?

Comment: forgot to mention, my question did based on idea of brain wallet

Comment: If you need to store it then you might as well encrypt a random private key. That way the private key cannot be guessed; an adversary would need to have access to the encrypted private key to test the possible passphrases (which should still be strong, of course).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes i know but is there a code for this?

Comment: The private key is encrypted both when stored in (encrypted) PKCS#8 or format (just the privatekey) or PKCS#12 format (private key and certificate). But you may want to make sure that the code to derive the encryption key from the password is using a strong algorithm such as PBKDF2 and a high iteration count...

Comment: um, i don't have any knowledge about PBKDF2 which is why i'm aking about sha-256

Comment: @Maarten+ for OpenSSL (as per Q) you can store a private key (including EC) in PKCS8 encrypted with PBES2 using PBKDF2 with 2048 iterations (good but not great) by calling `PEM_write[_bio]_PrivateKey` or `i2d_PKCS8PrivateKey[_nid]_{bio,fp}` with a 'plain' cipher e.g. from `NID_aes_128_cbc` instead of a specific `NID_pbe*` which are either PKCS5-PBES1 or PKCS12-PBE -- see the man pages.